# Find Page Last Modified at Certain Date & Time

Tags: pages

How can I find the page which was last modified on 2011-07-20T20:48:16+00:00 other than opening every page?

Comment: Are you needing this in your template, or is this just a one time lookup for reference?

Comment: Hi rtgibbons, Thank you for trying to help me. It was a one time reference. I've got it sorted now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I've got it.

I looked in wp_posts table in phpmyadmin, clicked on the post_modified column to get it in chronological order, and looked for the appropriate datetime.